# how fix broken libssl.so.1.1 in arch after update package?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

I did a dumb update and seems that I broke some packages in my arch (manjaro) distro, now paru, pacman and even a git install fails with this message:

`sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

what could be the best way to solve this issue and how can I prevent this in the future?

My machine hasn't so much disk space for a full update/upgrade...Is there a way to segment the installation and upgrade of my system? (I know it's highly likely that it won't, but I prefer to confirm)

thank you so much

Comment: that would only happen when you either installed some central component sidesteppung your distro's installation tools (which then, as you notice, breaks as you update things), or uninstalled something explicitly disabling dependency checks. Is it possible one of these things happened?

Comment: hello @MarcusMüller yes, it was the option A: I broke the opensl package (yes I know, it was a noob mistake)

Comment: You should definitely add that info to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never install something without doing a `sudo pacman -Syu` first. If you don’t have enough space to do this try clearing the package cache with `sudo pacman -Scc` and then `sudo pacman -Syu`. If space is still a problem try installing the larger updates individually and clear the cache each time. If individual packages cause the upgrade to fail set them to not be upgraded in pacman.conf (`IgnorePkg=packagename`). Once the upgrade has completed remove or hash out those IgnorePkg lines and upgrade again.

Good luck